# Is this Vector operation defined? Does it have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

Let's say I have 2 vectors:

```
[a, b, c]
[x, y, z]
```

And I need to do an operation like the following for a computer program:

```
[a*x, b*y, c*z]
```

What I want to know is if this operation is defined as a common vector operation? And what can I call it? I ask this because I can't find any information about it. Of course nothing tells me I can't do this, it may just not be a "normal" vector operation.

Comment: It is not so common in pure mathematics. It is called coordinatewise multiplication. In `matlab` this is called array multiplication would be written as `[a,b,c].*[x,y,z]`.

Comment: That would be a Hadamard product...

Comment: The name Hadamard product is also used for matrices http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Hadamard_product Google told me that the names "vector multiply" or "componentwise product" are also used http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/browse_thread/thread/503a15f78ef6f558/e464cfe894a29c3d

Comment: It's called the [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Hadamard_product), Schur product, or entrywise product.

Comment: Sometimes also component-wise product.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: You should post an answer, not add a comment.

Comment: I disagree that you should call the things you're multiplying vectors; this isn't a natural operation on geometric vectors. You should call them arrays or sequences. Also, I prefer the term _pointwise_ product.

Comment: Why was this question closed? The other linked question is not as descriptive as this one. If anything, the other question should be closed and linked back to this one.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: your question was closed because it is a duplicate of this. Those are the rules. This is **not** *your* question. You may suggest some improvements but you went way over the top. I rolled back to the the previous version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Component-wise multiplication (or coordinate-wise multiplication like @Theo mentioned in his comment).

Comment: I've seen this called *Element-wise* multiply too - http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html

Answer (score 8):

Your operation is the multiplication in the algebra of functions $\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\mathbb R$.

This algebra is *a* vector space with the obvious pointwise addition and scalar multiplication. It is isomorphic *as a vector space* to the usual $n$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb R^n$ (depending on the details of the formalization you work in, they may even be *identical* rather than simply isomorphic). Nevertheless, it is most common to think of it as something separate from $\mathbb R^n$.

Why is that? It is because usually when we speak about $\mathbb R^n$ we want to think of it as a concrete *representation* of some other vector space which we get by choosing a basis, and in most cases we have considerable liberty to choose the basis. Therefore $\mathbb R^n$ usually invokes an idea of "some abstract $n$-dimensional vector space with a more or less arbitrarily chosen basis".

However, your multiplication operation does not fit into this framework, because *it is not preserved* when we move to another basis. Therefore it is not a useful concept to speak of in the common situation where the basis *was* chosen more or less arbitrarily.

So in order to reduce the risk of confusion, we usually pretend that the component-wise product doesn't exist when we speak merely of $\mathbb R^n$. In the few situations where the multiplication *is* useful, we prefer to call the space something else such as to remind ourselves that our usual freedom to switch to another basis whenever it's convenient doesn't exist anymore.

In particular, you won't find the the Hadamard product listed in an article about "Euclidean vectors" -- because what makes the vectors *Euclidean* is that the relations between them do not change if we rotate the coordinate system. But the product *does* change if the coordinate system is turned.