# Symbol for elementwise multiplication of vectors

Tags: notation

This is a notation question. Assume one is given two vector $\mathbf{a}$  and $\mathbf{b}$, and one constructs a third vector $\mathbf{c}$ whose elements are given by 
$$c_k=a_k b_k$$ 
Is there any standard notation for this simple operation? 
Is the notation below acceptable?
$$\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{a}\otimes \mathbf{b}$$

Comment: Related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20412/element-wise-or-pointwise-operations-notation and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32516/is-this-vector-operation-defined-does-it-have-a-name

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19180/which-dot-character-to-use-in-which-context

Comment: since vector multiplication is overloaded quite a lot as is, you can't trust that any arbitrary reader will understand your notation; to avoid this problem, use any symbol you want as long as you leave a "let (*) denote pairwise multiplication of vectors" before using it or "where (*) denotes pairwise multiplication" after using it, and make sure that you only use this operator in this way in the context of (*) :: vector -> vector -> vector.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

(Minor edits.)

It turns out that the symbol $\odot$ is often used to denote component-wise multiplication (a few examples are given in the comments below); $\circ$ and $*$ are common alternatives.

Comment: Example 1: Last sentence in page 29 here: http://www.columbia.edu/~nsa2106/Aybat_Paper4_FALC.pdf

Comment: Example 2: The sentence above Equation (8) here: http://www.uow.edu.au/~mwand/publicns/Gangu07.pdf

Comment: Example 3: Line 10 on page 14 here http://www.stanford.edu/~tsachy/pdf_files/Algorithms%20for%20Discrete%20Denoising%20Under%20Channel%20Uncertainty.pdf.

Comment: Example 4: Last sentence on page 16 here: http://alphard.ethz.ch/Hafner/Workshop/Sandfort2010.pdf

Comment: Example 5: End of page 2 here: http://www.tu-ilmenau.de/fakia/fileadmin/template/startIA/neuroinformatik/publications/conferences_int/2007/Rebhan-ICANN-07.pdf

Comment: The links for the examples 1, 2, and 5 are broken at the time this written.

Comment: For latex users, the command for the symbol is `\odot`.

Comment: I do like this description, since $\otimes$ represents the Kronecker product as well.  Whereas $\odot$ is very clear that element-wise operations are intended.

Answer (score 24):

- Wikipedia uses $\circ$ (`\circ`) to denote the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (which is the operation you describe)
- [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/601545/389109) makes a
  good case for $\odot$ (`\odot`) being used instead.

Answer (score 11):

No, I would be concerned about $\otimes$ causing confusion with the [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#Definition) (although the outer product will produce a matrix, and the componentwise product will produce a vector, so if the context is clear enough perhaps this will not be a problem).

I recommend writing componentwise multiplication of vectors using some symbol that does not have a standard meaning, perhaps $\star$ (`\star`) or $\diamond$ (`\diamond`), so that people reading won't have any preconceptions about what might be meant.

Comment: Additionally, $\otimes$ is also often used for the Kronecker product, so using that to denote the Hadamard product would be quite the symbol overload...

Answer (score 11):

If I ever needed to perform a Hadamard product of two vectors $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$, apart from the usual MATLAB notation (as mentioned in the first linked question in the comments), I'd probably use $\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf a)\cdot\mathbf b$, where $\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf a)$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $a_k$.