# how to manipulte two vectors to result in a vector which elements are products of corresponding elements of the input vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

so I have 2 vectors. How do I manipulate them so I end up with the vector of the same size which elements are a product of the corresponding elements of the two vectors. How would I do that for an arbitrary number of vectors? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the same size?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean how you do it numerically?

Comment: hi, sorry for lack of clarity - I'll try to rephrase it(I'm not a math major). Let's say I have 2 2x1 vectors - I'd like to use matrix multiplication to arrive at a 2x1 vector which elements would be a product of the corresponding elements in the 1st two vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of the question:

> If you have vectors: $$\vec a = \langle a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\rangle$$
>   $$\vec b = \langle b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n\rangle$$
>
> How do you create the vector below? $$\vec c = \langle a_1b_1, a_2b_2, \ldots, a_nb_n\rangle$$

This is the exact definition of element-wise multiplication, which is actually a defined operation.  See this question (and those it is linked to) for more information: [Symbol for elementwise multiplication of vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52578/symbol-for-elementwise-multiplication-of-vectors)

EDIT: It appears this is also called the [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29).

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=(a_{11},a_{12},...a_{1n})_{1\times n}$ and if we want to have what you are looking for (the product of the correspondence elements), so another vector should have the form $w=(b_{i1})_{1}^{n}$.

Comment: I see you shortened your "user name", Babak S. Can you guess my first name: A + M + "WHY"?

Comment: @amWhy: Yes it is a fun. I hope it has not violated the rules here. Let me see..... A maybe is Arthur. M maybe Micheal... It is like a system of 4 unknowns and just one equation. Hard...

Comment: @amWhy: Eureka! Amy. Right?