# What is the name of the property $a^T(b\odot c)=b^T \text{diag}(a)c$, and what is the definition $b\odot c$?

Tags: matrices, vectors

In one of the research paper I read that $$\mathbb{a}^T(\mathbb{b}\odot \mathbb{c})=\mathbb{b}^T \text{diag}(\mathbb{a})\mathbb{c}$$ where $\mathbb{a},
\mathbb{b},\mathbb{c}$ are vectors of same size. What is the name of above property and what does $\mathbb{b}\odot \mathbb{c}$ means? Thanks in advance. Here is the snap shot of the paper I am reading [image]

Comment: Care to share the link to the research paper you are reading?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6317113 page 4028, 3rd line after equation (3)

Comment: And if it’s behind a paywall just attach a screenshot of the context.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @rschwieb.  The article as it is is behind a paywall.

Comment: @rschwieb I have added the screen shot of the paper. I have looked at the paper several times but I could not find where they defined the notation.

Comment: @FrankMoses it’s available for free at researchgate, for those of us who made accounts.

Comment: @rschwieb and I am so silly that I can not understand how your last comment answers my question in the post.

Comment: @FrankMoses I believe you now. Looks like it could be domain specific. I don’t think I’ve ever seen it.

Comment: @FrankMoses it doesn’t answer your question. It points out that there is a version which is available for free. So that people can use it to help you.

Comment: @rschwieb oh I understand it now. I was so silly that I thought people would not have such clairvoyant insights about my sillyness and will avoid making such statements about my sillyness.

Comment: Turns out to be related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52581/29335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation ${\rm diag}({\bf a})$ is defined in the paper you linked, page 4027, column 1, last line.  I have never used the notation $\odot$ but suspect that it is the elementwise product of two vectors, in which case for ${\bf a}=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ etc we have
$$\eqalign{
  {\bf a}^T({\bf b}\odot{\bf c})
  &=\pmatrix{a_1&\cdots&a_n\cr}\pmatrix{b_1c_1\cr\vdots\cr b_nc_n\cr}\cr
  &=a_1b_1c_1+\cdots+a_nb_nc_n\cr
  &=\pmatrix{b_1&\cdots&b_n\cr}\pmatrix{a_1c_1\cr\vdots\cr a_nc_n\cr}\cr
  &=\pmatrix{b_1&\cdots&b_n\cr}\pmatrix{a_1&\cdots&0\cr\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\cr0&\cdots&a_n\cr}\pmatrix{c_1\cr\vdots\cr c_n\cr}\cr
  &={\bf b}^T{\rm diag}({\bf a}){\bf c}\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I also think this is the case but they should have mentioned it in the paper

Comment: Good detective work. I've seen a couple things denoting the Hadamard/Schur/elementwise product, but not this. Actually, it did turn up on stack exchange in a solution [once before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52581/29335)