# Vector multiplication and normalisation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am studying for a paper, and would like to understand if the following operation represent a normalisation.

I have two vectors A, B of same length. I multiply their items, element-wise, sum the resulting vector, and divide by the sum of A.

(Hope the notation of element wise is correct, I looked at:
[Symbol for elementwise multiplication of vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52578/symbol-for-elementwise-multiplication-of-vectors))

Is it the following a type of normalisation ? Does it have a meaning in physics to help me understand the scope of this operation?

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf a \circ \mathbf b )} {\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf ai}$$

E.g. given a = [2,5], b = [3,7]   => [6,35].sum() / [2,5].sum() => $\frac{41}{7}$

Comment: In the denominator, you seem to be saying $2+5=10$

Comment: What is the paper? Can you provide a link for context?

Comment: tks saul, corrected. Spencer, corrected text  - sorry guys, yesterday night been a long day for me! The context is related to topological analysis, the objective is to extract properties of a network for training purpose. In the example above, a, b are two arrays of different types of quantities which are exchanged along edges of a network, say prices and quantities. So the final result measure would be in prices units (€ * Kg / Kg ).