# Is there a name for the element-by-element multiplication of two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vector-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this Vector operation defined? Does it have a name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32516/is-this-vector-operation-defined-does-it-have-a-name)

I am a software engineer, so bear with me.

Suppose I have two vectors of equal length containing numbers. Is there a name for the element-by-element multiplication of the two vectors together to get another vector of the same length?

For example [1 2 3] multiplied by [3 4 5] should get you [3 8 15].

I know it isn't "dot product" (which returns a scalar) or "cross product" (which returns a perpendicular vector). I looked through the operators listed in Wikipedia and could not find a suitable name:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Basic_properties

If, indeed, there is no name, does this signify that this isn't a common operation in vector-space math?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: The general method is to close *newer* questions that duplicate old ones.